# SQL - Divided multiple values by multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql, function, subquery, divide

```
Select AdClick.AdMonth AS DATE,
(SELECT SUM(AdBudget) FROM AdBudget GROUP BY AdMonth) / 
(SELECT SUM(AdClicks) FROM AdClick, AdReport 
WHERE AdReport.AdSourceID != 4
AND AdReport.AdSourceID = AdClick.AdSourceID
GROUP BY AdMonth) AS CPC
FROM AdClick, AdBudget, AdReport
WHERE AdClick.AdYear = '2016' 
GROUP BY AdClick.AdMonth
```

The `SUM(AdBudget)` and `SUM(AdClicks)` have `AdMonth` values attached in a table to separate the months, but I need to divide the SUMs that have the same month value. Grouping doesn't work because I can't have multiple values from a subquery be divided by another subquery with multiple values, so is there a way to divide the sum of AdMonth 1 by the sum of AdMonth 1 and sum of 2 by sum of 2...?

FYI: I am using the code to create a ColdFusion Chart, but these queries are called in ColdFusion documents, so ColdFusion solutions that work with charts are not off the table.

Answer (score 1):

Should be something like this. Inner join the tables together on month and source id, and group by months:

```
SELECT   AdClick.AdMonth  AS `DATE`
         , SUM(AdBudget.AdBudget)
         , SUM(AdClick.AdClicks)
         , SUM(AdBudget.AdBudget) / SUM(AdClick.AdClicks)
FROM    AdClick
           INNER JOIN AdBudget ON AdClick.AdMonth = AdBudget.AdMonth
           INNER JOIN  AdReport ON AdReport.AdSourceID = AdClick.AdSourceID
WHERE   AdClick.AdYear = '2016' 
AND     AdReport.AdSourceID != 4
GROUP BY AdClick.AdMonth
```

Comment: I need to divide the sums that have the same AdMonth, could you add that into the code?

Comment: Thanks! I figured my problem out using cfloops, but thanks for the answer.

Comment: scaisEdge - Yep. that is pretty much what I was going to suggest, only with an outer join. (Also, not sure if the base tables contain both a month and year. If yes, obviously join on the year column as well. ) @N.Ziff - Consider using a query instead.  Aggregating in SQL is usually more efficient than looping.

Comment: @Leigh I understand where you are coming from with the query, but when I tried a query similar to what you suggested, the query would take the SUM of ALL the budget and clicks etc and not just the sum from AdMonth 1 and AdMonth 2 etc...

Comment: Then you are probably not using the same query scaisEdge posted or there is something different about your tables than we are assuming ;-) I have used that technique before, and it does work.  Please update your question with a small data sample AND the *exact* sql you used, so we can help identify the problem with your query.  Use SQLFiddle to share the DDL's http://sqlfiddle.com/